# Overriding a property in a protocol to make it mutable

Tags: objective-c, properties

I'm having some issues trying to override a property in a protocol to make it mutable.

I have this protocol:

```
@protocol TheProtocol
     @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *someString;
@end
```

And this class:

```
@interface SuperObject : NSObject <TheProtocol>
@end
```

Which synthesizes the variable like so:

```
@implementation SuperObject
@synthesize someString;

-(id)init {
 if(self=[super init]) {
    someString = [aString copy];
 }
 return self;
 }

@end
```

and can thus write to it internally

I then have a subclass:

```
@interface SubObject : SuperObject 
@end

@implementation SubObject
@synthesize someString;

- (id)init {
  if(self=[super init]) {
    NSLog(@"Some string is %@",someString");
    someString = [bString copy];
  }
  return self;
}
```

In my subclass, trying to assign to someString doesn't work. I tried also synthesizing someString in my subclass but before I try and modify it, when I print out "someString", it prints nil instead of "something"

**Answered**

I figured out the answer.  Ultimately what worked is this:

```
@interface SuperObject : NSObject <TheProtocol> {
     @protected
     NSString *someString;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you synthesize in your subclass, that is allocating a different ivar than the one in your super class. Therefore the value when printed is `nil`. You can refer to the original ivar by doing `self.someString.`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Oscar.  I tried that (edited my original post) but it looks like it's messing with the superclass version because someString should be aString since I'm calling super's init.  Instead it's nil.

Comment: The protocol only declares the property, but there is no backing ivar, when the synthesize is done in each class, a new ivar is created. Therefore it is not the same ivar.

Comment: Is there a preferred way to do this that doesn't involve a different ivar getting allocated?  It seems confusing

Comment: From my testing, it seems that when I DON'T call synthesize, self.someString in my subclass has the right value.  However, when I do call synthesize, self.someString returns nil.  super.someString does not.